# SAS Concatenation based on values

Tags: sas, string-concatenation, sas-macro

Below is the sample data.

```
NAME VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
ABC    X   Y          2
DEF    P   Q    R     3
GHI    L              1
```

The count of variables (from VAR2-VAR4) is present under VAR5 for each record, I want the following output with NewVar as the concatenation of the variables which contain a value.

```
NAME VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5  NewVar
ABC    X   Y          2     X,Y
DEF    P   Q    R     3     P,Q,R
GHI    L              1     L
```

I have no clue how to do it in SAS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CATX()` function to concatenate the variables; with this function you have the option to specify the delimiter character to use between the values. Ex. `CATX(',',VAR2,VAR3,VAR4)`

Input Data:

```
data have;
input NAME $ VAR2 $ VAR3 $ VAR4 $ VAR5;
datalines;
ABC    X   Y    .      2
DEF    P   Q    R     3
GHI    L   .    .       1
;
run;
```

Solution:

```
data want;
set have;
NewVar= catx(',',VAR2,VAR3,VAR4);
run;
```

or

```
%let list=VAR2,VAR3,VAR4;
data want2;
set have;
NewVar= catx(',',&list.);
run;
```

or (Tom's Recommendation)

```
data want3;
set have;
NewVar= catx(',',of var2-var4);
run;
```

Output:

```
NAME=ABC VAR2=X VAR3=Y VAR4=  VAR5=2 NewVar=X,Y 
NAME=DEF VAR2=P VAR3=Q VAR4=R VAR5=3 NewVar=P,Q,R 
NAME=GHI VAR2=L VAR3=  VAR4=  VAR5=1 NewVar=L
```

Comment: Thanks momo1644, that was super easy, I was wondering if I can create  a macro for this depending on the number of variables I need to concatenate? for example... I do not want to type in catx(',',var1,var2,.....varn) everytime I need to do this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think a macro function would be practical here as you the catx() does the  join you want. But for less typing you can save the variable names in a macro variable instead. I'll add the code to my answer. Unless you want to concatenate all the fields in the table that contain VAR in its name.

Comment: If you want to use a variable list in a function call use the `OF` keyword. `newvar=catx(',',of var1-var5)` or `newvar=catx(',',of a b c e f)`

Comment: Yes, momo1644 all variables which need to be concatenated have a common prefix.

Comment: Tom's recommendation above will do this for you, I'll add it to my answer for comprehensiveness.